# Does CQRS Handler can invoke another Handler because of relations to another Domain?

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, cqs

I have read DDD Vaughn Vernon book. There is a info about CQRS architecture. He mention that Handler can only do one Handler task, which I understand his and he cannot invoke other Handler. And even If i skip that and I invoke other handler I can't return value to connect them like with keys.

So I have this kind of problem to solve.

I have two Domains one **Building** and second **Person**. By form on UI I attach Person to his building. Ofcourse I need to write them together on backend so I first invoke Main Domain Building with his `BuildingSaveCommandHandler` then in that action I invoke `PersonSaveCommandHandler` and return ID of that person so I can attach it to building (I know in CQRS I shouldn't do it like this). And Ofc I can do this in other way to attach Building to Person but I want like I said.

So my question are:

1. Can I invoke Handler into other Handler?
2. How can I connect separate Domains when saving them together if I can't return value from Command?

Comment: This question is an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). You are asking about (Y) how to execute multiples CQRS handlers, but the core issue here (X) is that you have a relationship which is defined twice. The general solution here is to not model the relationship this way. I'm not voting to close because I think this question can be saved with an edit that shifts the focus onto X instead of Y.

Comment: Probably you have right but my problem comes from Handler invocation, not from Domain relations, because I assume that can be somehow.

Comment: You shouldn't need to perform two saves in order to express one relationship. It's a flawed approach which is going to cause a lot of friction. And when you address that part so that the relationship is expressed in _one_ data element, then the focus of your direct question becomes moot.

Answer (score 2):

The two-way relationship between Building and Person is what's causing the friction.

Sometimes it can simply be solved by removing one end of the relationship. Ask yourself "why does building need to know about person?" and "why does person need to know about building?". If you can't answer one of those questions, remove the Id from the other aggregate.

If both need to know about each other, it's a sign of a missing domain concept. Create a new aggregate that knows about buildings and persons and give it a meaningful name. After you've done this, you only need a single command handler to update this aggregate.

Comment: Ok, I'm conscious that we can have separate relation like **Address** which connect **Building** and **Person** but they are also a separate Domain to the **Address**, and I need put key into the Building and the Person. Other handlers need to be invoked.